# cross-platform way to get a list of directories and run npm install in each of them

Tags: node.js, powershell, cmd

I'm running next command to do npm install for each module in modules directory

```
if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    return 'powershell -noprofile -command "Get-ChildItem ../modules | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % { Push-Location $_.FullName;  npm install; Pop-Location }"';
} else {
     return 'for dir in ../modules/*; do (cd $dir && pwd && npm install); done'
}
```

Are there more elegant ways to do that? Should be cross-platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should work on Windows and Linux systems:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var child_process = require('child_process');

fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'modules')
  .filter(function(dir) {
    return fs.statSync(path.join(__dirname, 'modules', dir)).isDirectory();
  })
  .forEach(function(dir) {
    child_process.spawnSync('npm', ['install'], {
      cwd: path.join(__dirname, 'modules', dir))
    });
  });
```

The script lists the directory contents, filters out non-directories, then executes `npm install` in each of the directories.